# how to allow two php queries every 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, spam

I've used this function for protection against spam queries:
but i want to make it allow two  queries every 5 seconds

```
function antiSpam($seconds) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_query']))
        $_SESSION['last_query'] = microtime(true);

    if($_SESSION['last_query'] >= microtime(true))
        exit(header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/spammer.php'));

    $_SESSION['last_query'] = microtime(true)+$seconds;
}

antiSpam(5);
```

any idea about how to fix that ?

Comment: Have you kept the last query in the session? I guess, in the same way, you can do for the second one.

Comment: Most webservers have rate limiting options. Use that instead of doing it in PHP.

Comment: Can't you just call `antiSpam(2.5)` rather than `antiSpam(5)` at the bottom?